# Getting results of service in MainActivity

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-service

How to *continuously* get the results from a service to UI or MainActivity.?

I am copying some large file using a service,and i want to update the progress bar in Foreground.

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is to use Singleton object with listener.
Subscribe for update in activity and just set values in Service.

```
public class ProgressSingleton {
    private static ProgressSingleton instance;

    private ProgressListener progressListener = null;

    public static void initInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProgressSingleton();
        }
    }

    public static ProgressSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private ProgressSingleton() {
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        if (progressListener != null) {
            progressListener.onProgressUpdated(progress);
        }
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {
        void onProgressUpdated(int progress);
    }
}
```

Make shure that you handle updates from listener in UI thread.
Also you can start your service in foreground, best option for big files.

Comment: The better way is to use a runnable and update the progress every few seconds.